# a controller and its dependencies in a template

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller for a generic list view:

```
(angular
 .module('app.controllers')
 .controller('ItemListContr', [
     /*****/ '$scope', 'ItemData',
     function($scope,   ItemData,) {
         ...
     }
 ])
);
```

where `ItemData` is not the name of an existing component, but a placeholder name for a service that I inject into the controller from a route:

```
(angular
 .module('app', ['app.controllers', 'app.services'])
 .config([
     /******/ '$routeProvider',
     function ($routeProvider) {
         $routeProvider
             .when('/books', {
                 controller: 'ItemListContr',
                 resolve: {ItemData: 'BookData'},
                 templateUrl: 'book-list.html'
             })
             .when('/magazines', {
                 controller: 'ItemListContr',
                 resolve: {ItemData: 'MagazineData'},
                 templateUrl: 'magazine-list.html'
             })
     }])
);
```

where `BookData` and `MagazineData` are services defined in `app.services` module.

I also need to use this controller inside a template:

```
<span ng-controller="ItemListContr">...</span>
```

but I need to supply the data source `ItemData` for it. And I do not know how to do it from a template.

Comment: Try to set up a plunker http://plnkr.co would help

Comment: I believe that you can't achieve what you are trying to do here without writing a custom directive. Technically you could do it be replicating behavior of ngView using the `$controller` service. More info here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngView.js#L149 The real question thought it: why you need to have such ability? What is your use case? From there the `ItemData` would be coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$injector` to get your service by name in the controller.

Like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.value('ItemData', 'BookData')

myApp.service('BookData', function () {
    return {
        test: function () {
            alert("Test called in BookData!");
        }
    }
});

myApp.controller('ItemListContr', function ($scope, $injector, ItemData) {
    var myService = $injector.get(ItemData);
    myService.test();
});
```

And here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qssgz2gf/)