# how to create an instance of a service?

Tags: angularjs

I have a service:

```
(angular
 .module('app.services', ['ngResource'])
 .factory('MyService', [
     /******/ '$resource',
     function ($resource) {
         return $resource('myurl');
     }
 ])
);
```

I need to create an instance of it in my code. I know that angular can inject it if I list it as one of the parameters, but I am not asking about that. I need to create an instance of it "manually". How is it done?

EDIT:

this is related to my other question: [a controller and its dependencies in a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259369/a-controller-and-its-dependencies-in-a-template)

basically, I have a generic controller that takes a service as a parameter, and I need to create this controller manually using `$controller` object (to be able to use it in my template - please see the referenced question), and I need to supply a service object to it. My service needs an integer as a parameter, so I need to instantiate the service and set this integer on it as a property. Otherwise of course I would have just given the name of the service as a string to the `$controller`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to accomplish that can't be done with injection?

Comment: "My service needs an integer as a parameter" That would make the service stateful and angular doesn't really handles stateful services with Dependency Injection.  Where does that int come from?  Can another injected service / constant supply it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if [$injector](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24injector) suits your needs.